# How to store/save Timer/Threads instances running in WCF service

Tags: wcf, multithreading, timer, instance, scheduler

I'm trying to make a simple scheduler service that will automatically send emails, etc.

For now I have simple WCF service in which I create an instance of a timer, set a callback and do some work in the callback. Now this part works fine, with the callback being called and the work in it being done as expected.

The issue is I need to make some change to the timer, say change the interval or maybe just stop it.

But I can't seem to figure out a way to store/get the instance of that timer that I created. As each time I create a new proxy and access the service, I get a new instance of the service...

I know I could use a static variable but that kind of makes it a 'singleton' service, and the service host I am using at the current time does not support that...

So how can I get that instance of a timer/thread that I actually created in a previous call? Or am I just going about this the wrong way?

Comment: i.e. you can't use ServiceBehaviorAttribute and set InstanceContextMode to InstanceContextMode.Single?

Comment: No, the host does not support that at present. Actually the service host automatically does scaling...that is it could deploy a new instance of any given service if it thinks it's required...

Answer (score 0):

Static isn't all that bad of an idea here. Maybe that static is a dictionary keyed by a Guid and the Guid is returned to the client. Subsequent client calls use the Guid parameter, so new instances of your service lookup the timer using the Guid.